# Bootstrap v3.3.7 setting navbar's search input width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm not a seasoned Bootstrap user and I'm facing the following problem:

```
<header class="header">
  <nav class="primary-nav navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#primary-nav" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Hello</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="primary-nav">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Welcome</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Bar</a></li>
        </ul>
        <form class="search navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="has-clear">
              <input autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" class="form-control" id="search-input" placeholder="Search..." type="text">
              <span aria-hidden="true" class="form-control-clear glyphicon " id="clear-search"></span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

See the companion [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KNxpqJ).

With this pretty trivial navbar setup, there are two things I have difficulties correcting:

1. I don't understand why I need custom CSS to get rid of search box's `margin-bottom`, imho **stock bootstrap CSS should handle this** but maybe I've made a mistake
2. I couldn't find a way to reliably make the search input fill the navbar's width without specifying an absolute width in px

While I can manage 1., I can't achieve a proper behavior for the navbar's search input that should take full width and disappear when the "hamburger" menu appears.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

use this css

```css
#search-input{
  width: 100px;//specify width according to your requirement
}
```

Comment: I want to avoid setting explicit width in px. I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

visualize it in fullscreen

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#primary-nav" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Hello</a>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="primary-nav">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Welcome</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Foo</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Bar</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
          <div class="form-group" style="display:inline;">
            <div class="input-group" style="display:table;">
              <input autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" class="form-control" id="search-input" placeholder="Search..." type="text">
              <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:1%;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: I've seen that `width: 1%` trick on an `input-group-addon` already. The thing is I don't want such an addon.

Comment: honestly, this is the only trick that I know. I knows some other ones but they have almost the same idea. all of them make a span or a button and set its width to 1%. I hope that I find an other trick too. good luck.